# Are there any known plastic constant triangles?

Tags: geometry, constants, tessellations

I am trying to determine if there are any known plastic constant triangles. By this I mean specifically triangles for which all sides are powers of the plastic constant, $p\approx1.324717957244746$. The problem is that if you try to Google *plastic constant triangles* you'll find everything you wanted to know about recycling plastic, but nothing about the question I've posed here.

Comment: a trivial case is equilateral triangle

Comment: Putting the search term in quotations with give you better results. That is, search for           '  "plastic number" triangle  '

Comment: $(p,p^2,p^3).$ The only requirement is the triangle inequality,

Comment: Do you include $p^0$ as a possible side length?

Comment: found all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of them are of the form
$$ p^k \cdot( 1,p^a,p^{a+b})  $$
for non-negative integers $a,b,k$ with some restrictions:

(I) if $b=0$ we can allow any $a$

(II) if $b=1$ we demand $a \leq 3. \;$ NOTE $p^5-p^4 = 1.$

(III) if $b=2$ we demand $a=0. \;$ NOTE $p^3 - p = 1.$

Any $p^k$ times one of these:
$$ (1,p^a,p^a); \; \;  (1,1,p); \; \; (1,p,p^2); \; \;  (1,p^2,p^3); \; \;  (1,p^3,p^4); \; \; (1,1,p^2).  $$

we cannot allow $b > 2$

Comment: Thanks for your helpful reply. I had already found two of the three non-trivial solutions. Encouraged by your answer, I thought to allow +/- half-powers of  $p$. To that end, I found an additional 5 solutions. However, there may be more yet, as I have limited myself to solutions that are gnomons of isosceles plastic triangles with a unit base.

Comment: @CyeWaldman if you define $q = \sqrt p$ so that $q^6 = q^2 + 1$ and $q \approx 1.15,$ you ought to be able find all triangles $(1, q^a, q^{a+b})$ for integers $a,b \geq 0,$ just separate cases $b=0,$ then $b=1,$ then $b=2,$ until $b$ gets too large and no more are possible. It appears $b \geq 14$ is impossible as $q^{14} (q-1) > 1.$

Answer (score 3):

The golden ratio $r = \phi$ satisfies $\,1+r=r^2\,$ which implies that a triangle with sides $\,1,r,r^2\,$ is degenerate. But, for any real number $r$ such that $1/\phi<r<\phi\,$, then since $1+r > r^2, 1+r^2>r, \,$ and $r+r^2>1,\,$ implies that the triangle with sides $\,1,r,r^2\,$ is **not** degenerate. Applying this to $\,r=p\,$, since $\, 1/\phi<1<p<\phi\,$ the triangle with sides $\,1,p,p^2\,$ is not degenerate. Of course, you can multiply all three sides of the triangle by the same power of $p$ resulting in a triangle with sides $\,p^k,p^{k+1},p^{k+2}.\,$ There are other possibilites along the same lines and they have to satisfy the triangle inequalities.

Answer (score 3):

You can put [19 points in 3D space](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PoweredCliquePolyhedra/) so that the distance between any two is an integer power of the square root of the plastic constant. This structure contains most of the plastic-power triangles.  Many of these triangles have unusual properties, some of which I cover at [Shattering the Plane](https://blog.wolfram.com/2019/03/07/shattering-the-plane-with-twelve-new-substitution-tilings-using-2-phi-psi-chi-rho/). Below, you can see a distance matrix for the $K_{19}$ structure.

[image][image]

Also, you can arrange a progressive series for a perfect rectangle dissection.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for such a thoughtful reply. I shall enjoy going through 'Shattering the Plane.'

Answer (score 2):

The triangle inequality says that for a triangle of sides of lengths $a, b, c$, the following inequalities all hold: $a < b + c$ and $b < c + a$ and $c < a + b$. If $c$ is the longest side of the triangle, then we need only check that last one.

I'm assuming that you don't want an equilateral triangle with sides $p, p, p$.

So one possibility is to have an isosceles triangle with sides $1, 1, p$. This triangle is valid, because $p < 1 + 1 = 2$. The triangle with sides $p, p, 1$ also works.

A more interesting plastic triangle might have sides $1, p, p^2$. This is also a valid triangle, since $0<p<\sqrt{2}$, so $p^2 < 2 < 1 + p$